# Complexity in cases excellent, average and bad

Tags: java, algorithm, complexity-theory

I created this method in java that indicates whether an integer array is sorted or not. What is its complexity? I think if good is O(1) in the worst case is O(n) in the average case?

```
static boolean order(int[] a){
  for(int i=0;i<a.length-1;i++){
    if(a[i]>a[i+1]) return false;
  }
 return true;
}
```

Comment: You are asking about average? Because your good and worst cases seems correct to me.

Comment: average case depends on the statistical properties of your input... maybe you want to add that you want average case assuming uniform distribution of the input?

Comment: Yes, in the average case?

Comment: Wouldn't be faster if you distribute the comparison tasks to multiple threads? They would execute it in less time IMHO, especially if the size of the array is big enough. However, this requires multi-core CPU to provide the parallel execution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't tell anything about your input. So suppose it's totally random. So for any 2 neighbour pairs we have 50% chance that they are ordered.  It means that we have probability 1 of making 1 step, 0.5 for 2 steps, 0.25 for 3 steps and generally 2^(-k) for k steps. Let's calculate expected number of steps:

[image]

I don't know how to calculate sum of this series so I used wolfram alpha and got [answer: 2](http://bit.ly/UYiEsT), so it's a constant.

So as I understand average case for random input is O(1).

I'm not sure it is correct way to calculate average complexity but seems fine to me.

Comment: don't you mean probability 1/2 of making 1 comparison, 1/4 of making 2 comparisons, etc. ?

Comment: and there is a typo? in your equation... (1/(2^-k)) = 2^k.  this thing would explode...  it's not what you described in the text.

Comment: @thang yes, I mean 1/2 for 1, 1/4 for 2 and etc. I'll fix typo about in formula, thanks

Comment: seems it should be k/2^k for k=1,2,... because k=1, means 1/2 (1 iteration, 1/2 probability), k=2 means 2 * 1/4 (2 iterations, 1/4 probability), and so on...

Comment: @thang hm, no, I think it is k+1. Because you make 1 comparison with 1 probability, 2 comparisons with 1/2, 3 with 1/4, etc.

Comment: @thang anyway it doesn't change result really. It becomes 2 instead of 4, so it's still constant.

Comment: if you make 1 comparison with probability of 1, then you're done... probability can only go to 1.  the first probability has to be 1/2, then next is 1/4... you're right it doesn't change the result, but it's good to have the equation right.  basically, there is a 50% chance that you stop after the first comparison.  after that, 50% chance that you stop after the second comparison (marginal), so 25% chance over all... etc...

Comment: I don't understand why we don't add the 1. We will definitely make one comparison, so probability of making one is 1. Then we have 0.5 chances for 2, 0.25 for 3 and so on. The +1 should stay when computing the expected number of comparisons.

Comment: @IVlad when you calculate expected value you have to sum all possible values multiplied by their probabilites. And sum of probabilites must be 1. Here is probability of making **exactly** one comparison is 1/2, **exactly** 2 comparions = 1/4, etc.

Comment: Yes, but you have 100% chances of making one comparison (the first). The probability computation takes place after we exclude that one, but we should add it back to the final answer, which should then be 3.

Comment: @IVlad If you add 1 to all cases then you have following formula: `1 + (0*1/2 + 1*1/4 + 2*1/8 + ...)` which is actually formula in my answer.

Comment: Why not `1 + <your formula>`? Your formula starts from `1/2` probability for 1 iteration, but this only holds if you ignore the first iteration, which has 100% probability. You can ignore it so your probabilities add up correctly, but shouldn't it be added back in the end?

Comment: If you add 1 to all elements in my formula then you won't get 1 iteration because you you'll get at least 2 iteration for.

Comment: I didn't say add 1 to all elements, I meant exactly `1 + <your formula> = 3`.

Comment: @IVlad then again you take **any** probability from my formula and you get **always** at least 2 iterations.

Comment: The way I see it, you are reasoning like this: 1/2 probability of making **another** comparison other than the mandatory first, 2/4 of making another still etc. This gets you 2 expected **extra** comparisons, and with the initial one that always takes place, 3.

Comment: +1 I thought the answer was `O(n)` until I read yours. Good work! It reminds me of randomized algorithms in my undergraduate courses.

Answer (score 0):

Complexity is usually quoted in worst case, which in your case is O(n).

Comment: @Enzo if you think the average case is relevant then you need to think about your input, we can't predict what that's going to be.

Comment: @Qwerky When analyzing "average case" you usually do it with a random input, and calculate the *expected value* (mean) of the cost - this gives you the average case complexity. For example, in this case it should be done with all possible permutations, giving each permutation prbability of 1/n! to be chosen.